# How can i uncheck leader lines show in piechart using ArcObject?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I'd like to uncheck the leader lines of my piecharts programmatically . I surf in the internet and found nothing about this.It's simple to uncheck the leader lines in ArcMap. Just go to properties of the piechart and Uncheck Show Leader lines but How can i uncheck the capability using ArcObject? What Interface and Property should i use to unchek th leader lines ? 
I'm using ArcGIS 10, ArcEngine 10,c# language
Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem this morning. After navigating through the arcgis documentation, I finally found a way to remove these lines.

In c++ : 
where ipPieChartSym Is the pie chart symbol you created to assing to the renderer.

```
IMarkerBackgroundSupportPtr ipMarkerBackgroundSupport(ipPieChartSym);

IMarkerBackgroundPtr ipMarkerBackground;
ipMarkerBackgroundSupport->get_Background(&ipMarkerBackground);

ILineCalloutPtr ipLineCallout(ipMarkerBackground);
//This line will remove the leader line
ipLineCallout->putref_LeaderLine(NULL);
```